# How to reduce the length of a string?

Tags: python, compression

I'm trying to reduce the size of a string like this:

```
'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE0NDU0OTk3NDUsImQiOnsiYXV0aF9kYXRhIjoiZm9vIiwib3RoZXJfYXV0aF9kYXRhIjoiYmFyIiwidWlkIjoidW5pcXVlSWQxIn0sInYiOjB9.h6LV3boj0ka2PsyOjZJb8Q48ugiHlEkNksusRGtcUBk'
```

to something that someone could type in less then 30 seconds like this:

```
'aF9kYX'
```

and be able to turn it back to the original string too. How could I achieve that?

EDIT: I guess I'm not being clear, first I don't know if what I want is possible. 
So, I have my app which asks for a token to log in, which is that JWT. But it is way too long for someone to manually type. So I supposed there was an algorithm to make this string smaller (compress it) so that it could be easier and faster to type. An example that comes to my mind of how I would use such algorithm is:

```
short_to_big(small_string) //Returns the original JWT
big_to_short(JWT_string)   //Returns the smaller string
```

Comment: Do you just want to store a bunch of long strings and then retrieve them, or do you want to somehow compress and decompress arbitrary strings?

Comment: The mapping from the first set to the second is clearly not 1-1, meaning there's going to be a string `s` from the second set that maps to multiple strings from the first. The question is what do you want to do if given `s`?

Comment: That appears to be a JSON Web Token. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Whatever you're doing, you're decreasing the effectiveness of the JWT scheme.

Comment: I want to compress and decompress the string so that its easier and faster to type, I'm not sure if that's the correct way of saying it.

Comment: Indeed it is a JWT, it is generated from the python firebase helper library.
I want to give different tokens to selected users for my app, so that they could log in with that, but it is way too long to type.

Comment: @Fergarram pro-tip: when people ask what you mean, don't just say the same thing again, because *that clearly didn't help*.

Comment: So, you need to compress and decompress strings, but you plan on doing a simple lookup? A lookup which defeats the purpose of a large key in the first place... It sounds like you're trying to reinvent either cookies or user logins; I'm not sure which.

Comment: You should read e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token - why does it matter if it's too long to remember? It's not designed to be, and if you ever actually need to enter it somewhere you would just cut and paste it.

Comment: OP, what's the last website you used where you had to log in with something like "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ..." instead of "Fergarram" or your email address? How about a website where you had to log in with merely "aF9kYX"? The answers to those questions should tell you something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so, because I couldn't find a solution for shrinking the string, I tried to give it a different approach, and found a solution.

Now to clarify why I wanted to log in with the token, I'm going to write what I want to do with my app:

In Firebase anyone can create an account, but I don't want that, so for that I made a group of users that were the only ones that could write or read the data.

So in order to create an account, the user would have to request a register code, (Which in reality is a JWT generated from Firebase, so that you have permission to add a user to that group I was talking about).

This app is for local use, meaning that only people that lives here are going to use it. So, back to the original question, the token is too big for someone to type (as I have said many times), and I wanted to know if I could shrink it and how. But without success I tried a different approach, which is to generate the token (from a different program), encrypt it with a random code, and upload it to a firebase, that way I give the random code to people so that users can type it in the app so that it can retrieve and decrypt the token and authenticate with it, so that finally the user has an account that has the privilege to read or write data.

Thanks for your responses and sorry if I wasted your time.

Comment: 1. This should be an edit to your question, not an answer. 2. You are reinventing user logins.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid simple answer: use a dict to store the short string as key and the long one as value. Then you just have to generate the short string the way you like and make sure it's not already in the dict. If you need to persist the key/value, you can use almost any kind of database (sql, key:value, document, or even a csv file FWIW).

Oh and if that doesn't solve your problem then you may want to consider giving more context ;)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** (After question clarification and comments suggestion)

You could implement an algorithm that **uniquely** maps this big string into a short representation of the string and store this mapping in a dictionary. The following algorithm does not guarantee the *uniqueness* but should give you some path to follow.

```
import random
import string

def long_string_to_short(original_string, length=10):
    random.seed(original_string)
    filling_values = string.digits + string.ascii_letters
    short_string = ''.join(random.choice(filling_values) for char_ in xrange(length))
    return short_string
```

When calling the function you can specify an appropriate length for the short string.

Then you could:

```
my_mapping_dict = {}
my_long_string = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE0NDU0OTk3NDUsImQiOnsiYXV0aF9kYXRhIjoiZm9vIiwib3RoZXJfYXV0aF9kYXRhIjoiYmFyIiwidWlkIjoidW5pcXVlSWQxIn0sInYiOjB9.h6LV3boj0ka2PsyOjZJb8Q48ugiHlEkNksusRGtcUBk'
short_string = long_string_to_short(my_long_string)
my_mapping_dict[short_string] = my_long_string
```

Comment: I like the way you've hidden the whole of the actual answer in `get things done and generates a short representation`...

Comment: @jonrsharpe - You think he should [be more explicit here in step 2](http://star.psy.ohio-state.edu/coglab/Pictures/miracle.gif)?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 yes, that expresses it perfectly!

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well, it's only a matter of reading the question... Is it explicit or clear enough? Does he suggest anything that he has already tried? If he had, well, then I would have suggested a way of doing something more explicitly, other than that I can only suggest a way of mapping one string into another (which would answer the part "turn it back to the original string too").

Comment: No, it isn't *"explicit or clear enough"*, so **don't answer**.

Comment: Hmm, ok... so I can't answer the part of the question that is clear because some other part is not clear, and then keep discussing about it and edit my answer (when the user clarifies the other part)? I guess your funny joke was way more constructive, right?

Comment: There are no clear parts. All you've answered is "put an algorithm into a function," which is basically a restatement of the question. If you need clarification, the place to do that is in comments, not in an answer.

Comment: "...and be able to turn it back to the original string too. How could I achieve that?" - This part seems clear enough for me. But you guys want to polemize, right? Would you feel better if i delete the answer?

Comment: That was clear enough... for you to produce "get things done." This is just a stub.

Comment: No man, that was clear enough for suggesting him to use a dictionary data structure to map the short string into the long string, because that was part of his question (is it really that hard to get?).

His question is composed by (1) The need of an algorithm for doing something that is not completely clear in the question; (2) The need of mapping the result of that algorithm into the original string. But  as I said before, you want to polemize about it...

Comment: *"this algorithm isn't deterministic"* - that algorithm **is** deterministic, because you're using `seed`. It may well also return the same short string for two different long strings, which would be a problem. Also, side note, I would write the function to return the short string, and handle the dictionary elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need more constraints. A 200 character string contains a lot more information than a 6 character string, so either need to a lot more about the original strings (e.g. that they come from some known set of strings, or have a limited character set) or you need to store the original strings somewhere and use the string the user type as a key to a map or similar.

There are lossless compression algorithms, but these depend on knowing some probabilistic information about the string (e.g. that repeated characters are likely) and will typically expand the strings if the probabilities are wrong.